# How to make a slideshow of Views?

Tags: javascript, views

i want to make a slideshow block of two views.

view 1 is 'most popular blog posts', showing 10 titles with date and no. of times viewed.
view 2 is 'most commented blog posts', showing 10 titles with date and no. of comments.

I'll put the slideshow block on the front page, it will show view 1 first then after 5 seconds, it will show view 2.

How?

Answer (score 3):

By using the [Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module.

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.

Answer (score 1):

Use this and all your problem get solved: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module.

> This module allows developers and themers to make use of the jCarousel
>   jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use,
>   as well as Views integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn
>   any list of content or images into a carousel.

1. Enable the module
2. Goto View -> Select Format of type jCarousel
3. Configure the settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views Slideshow module for views sliding.

click here for module installation [SlideShow Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

and  [Click Here](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-slideshow-in-drupal-7/) and follow those steps to how to install slideshow module and configure the module in your site.